# AJAX not sending variable to write on txt

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So after a lot of tries, I managed to squeeze in ajax in my code to send a javascript variable value to php code on the same file (index.php), but it's not sending the variables. I've seen two similar questions on this site but none of them seem to do the trick for me.

This is the javascript code, it basically adds +1 to num, then, i put that keynum is the same value as num and send keynum through AJAX (supposedly)

```
<script>
   num=1;

   keynum=1;

  function nextnum()

 {

        document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").innerHTML) + 1;
        keynum=document.getElementById("num").innerHTML;
        alert(keynum);
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                url: 'index.php',
                data: {voteid: keynum},

    });
            }
```

And here is the PHP code, basically it recieves the value that ajax sends (supposedly) and it creates a text file with keynum value but everytime, the text file appears blank.

```
<?php
  $keynum = $_POST['keynum'];
  $post = "INSERT INTO post (keynum) VALUES ($keynum)";
 $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/num.txt";
   $file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
   $content = $keynum;
   fwrite($file,$content);
   fclose($file);
  echo 'Response';
  die();
  ?>
```

Comment: you explicitly set `{voteid: keynum}` but in PHP you access `$_POST['keynum']`, you access the key `voteid` not `keynum`, the `keynum` is the value

Comment: OMG, i'm retarded. It works, I'll keep the question up as an example of a working code of ajax.

Comment: @MiguelCasanova - if this works, there is no need to keep this up as a "working example", there are millions on the internet already, and please refrain for derogatory terms such as the way you described yourself in your comment

Comment: @MiguelCasanova yep, sometimes this moments happen, i agree with Sam though, no need to keep this question as there are already a lot of resources for this kind of question. if something goes wrong, get a cup of coffee, it helps

Comment: @MiguelCasanova - just a tip for you, one of my favourite tools is the cheapest, buy a rubber duck, when something isn't working, explain it to the duck, line by line, it often helps you find the issue, you'll feel mad for a short time, but it helps! :) https://rubberduckdebugging.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not getting properly the parameter from $_POST. 
You are doing `$_POST['keynum']` and it should be `$_POST['voteid']` because that is the name you put to the post param in jour ajax

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data in your ajax as follows:

```
{voteid: keynum}
```

where voteid is the key and value is value inside the keynum.

So, you will have to access the variables as `$_POST['voteid']`

If you see a similar problem in the future, use `var_dump` to debug.

example:

```
var_dump($_POST);die(); // prints the data inside the $_POST var
```

a small function that i use:

```
// in my index.php
function dd($v){
    var_dump($v); die();  
}

// where ever I want
dd($_POST);
```

Hope it helps.